# PostgreSQL: How to sum distinct in a single query?

Tags: database, postgresql

I've been working on a small summary table that reads from the following:

```
create table page_event (
  user_id uuid,
  viewed_at timestamp,
  type smallint,
  product_id integer,
  ad_id integer
);
```

And my query is quite simple:

```
select
  type,
  product_id,
  count(*) as counts,
  count(distinct user_id) as uniques
from
  page_event
where
  created_at >= '2023-09-01 14:17:00' and created_at < '2023-09-01 14:17:59'
group by
  type,
  product_id
```

However, this result gives me the event types separated. `type` can be 0, 1, 2, 3, in fact it is an application-side enum. Currently, I'm aggregating that in application code and inserting into a summary table. It is pretty fast and that's enough for the use case. However, I was wondering if it would be possible to do this in a single-query, so I could get the results of that select directly into the INSERT of my summary table.

I tried the following:

```
select
  product_id,
  sum(case when type = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as search,
  sum(case when type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as sidebar,
  sum(case when type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as pdp
from
  page_event
where
  created_at >= '2023-09-01 14:17:00' and created_at < '2023-09-01 14:17:59'
group by
  product_id
```

But I can't `sum()` with `distinct (user_id)`. This is how the summary table looks like:

```
create table event_summary (
  created_at timestamp,
  product_id integer,
  ad_id integer,
  search integer,
  unique_search integer,
  sidebar integer,
  unique_sidebar integer,
  pdp integer,
  unique_pdp integer
);
create index on event_summary using BRIN (created_at);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may always use a [FILTER clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) for this purpose (not only for `count`, but also for `count distinct`

*Example*

```
select 
  product_id,
  count(distinct user_id) filter (where type = 1) cnt_dist_1,
  count(*)  filter (where type = 1) cnt_1
from t
group by 1
order by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to count distinct users for each type then use `count()` combined with `distinct` :

```
    select
      product_id,
      count(distinct case when type = 0 then user_id end) as search,
      count(distinct case when type = 1 then user_id end) as sidebar,
      count(distinct case when type = 2 then user_id end) as pdp
    from
      page_event
    where
      created_at >= '2023-09-01 14:17:00' and created_at < '2023-09-01 14:17:59'
    group by
      product_id
```